# Excel VBA Select Last Row With Ctrl End in a worksheet

Tags: excel, range, vba

How do I adjust the below code to work with the equivalent of crtl shift end in VBA (which I think is xlLastCell or xlCellTypeLastCell)?

My sheet has 64 columns I only want to select Column 1 to 58 where I have data starting on row 2.   The below works unless the sheet is blank and then all rows from row 2 to 1048575 are selected.   Because I have protected cells below row 200,000 my script errors with the below.

```
With Worksheet(WorkSheet)
.Range(.Cells(2,1).End(XlDown),.Cells(2,58)).Select
End With
Selection.ClearContents
```

Comment: You are missing a period in front of the first cells

Comment: you are missing a prefacing period in `.Cells(2,1).End(XlDown)`.

Answer (score 0):

Start at row 200,000 and look up.

```
With Worksheet(WorkSheet)
    .Range(.Cells(200000, "A").End(XlUP), .Cells(2, "BF")).ClearContents
End With

'possible alternate to avoid clearing row 1
With Worksheet(WorkSheet)
    .Range(.Cells(200000, "A").End(XlUP).offset(1, 0), .Cells(2, "BF")).ClearContents
End With
```

Comment: thank you.  Any way to do this dynamically?   I have other functions that determine the first row with data and which columns that will be selected.   I put value above in my example but these are determine dynamically.   I don't want to hard code the 200000 in case this changes in the future.

Comment: That sounds like another question.